# 2003 Honda Accord Vibration and noise in engine

Tags: honda, accord, vibration

My 2003 Honda Accord is shaking while idling, and every once in a while there is a rattle in the engine like something is loose. I have had it checked out, and replaced all of the engine mounts to no avail, nothing is working. I'm not sure what else to do... it does not do it while im driving, only when the car is idling

Comment: How long since you've done a tune up? A rough idle is commonly caused by worn out spark plugs. Have a mechanic check it because this is not something you want to ignore.

Comment: Do you experience the issue if it's in Park?  Does it get worse when you are stopped and in Drive?   Is your air conditioner ON when this occurs or OFF......or it that completely irrelevant?

Comment: The rough idle does not happen when it is in park, and it is worse when the AC or Heater is on. I may need a tune up again, but I got one a couple years ago and it was still idling rough. it has been an issue that has just progressively gotten worse with time, and nobody can tell me why its doing it. I have spent thousands of dollars now

Comment: v6 or 4 cylinder? When the engine starts to idle rough what is your RPM's at roughly?

Comment: its a 4 cylinder, and it is around 6000-7000 rpm